# Why this code raise slice bound out of range?

Tags: go

I have no idea why this code always slice bound out of range:

```golang
parts := make([]string, 0, len(encodedCode)/4)

for i := 0; i < len(encodedCode); i += 4 {
    parts = append(parts, encodedCode[i:4])
}
```

`encodedCode` is string with length always multiply with 4. That mean `encodedCode[i:4]` never out of bound.

Comment: The code above will raise an exception if it reaches the third iteration through the loop, because the slice range will be illegal.  If the lower bound is numerically larger than the high bound, you'll see the runtime error "slice bounds out of range".  See: http://play.golang.org/p/dl4VRaEn0r as an example.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Slices are [idx_start:idx_end+1], not [idx_start:length]

Try this.

```
parts := make([]string, 0, len(encodedCode)/4)
for i := 0; i < len(encodedCode); i += 4 {
    parts = append(parts, encodedCode[i:i+4])
}
```

Good examples @ http://blog.golang.org/go-slices-usage-and-internals